# fstream does not work well with Pin

Tags: c++, binary, instrumentation, intel-pin

I've written a very simple Pin tool that only contains one instrumention function, that is, `instruction` below. It has no analysis function/callback. Its purpose is to only store the address of instructions that may be executed.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
#include "pin.H"

std::ofstream of1;
std::list<uint64_t> instrList;
uint64_t instrCount = 0;

VOID instruction(INS ins, VOID* v)
{
    ADDRINT ip = INS_Address(ins);
    of1 << ip << std::endl;
    of1.flush();
    instrList.push_back(ip);
    ++instrCount;
}

VOID finishFunc(INT32 code, VOID *v)
{
    of1.close();

    std::ofstream of2;
    of2.open("out2.txt", std::ofstream::out);
    of2 << std::hex;
    for (std::list<uint64_t>::iterator i = instrList.begin(); i != instrList.end(); ++i)
        of2 << *i << std::endl;
    of2.close();

    std::cerr << "Instruction count: " << instrCount << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    PIN_Init(argc, argv);

    of1.open("out1.txt", std::ofstream::out);
    of1 << std::hex;

    INS_AddInstrumentFunction(instruction, 0);
    PIN_AddFiniFunction(finishFunc, 0);

    PIN_StartProgram();

    return 0;
}
```

The contents of the files `out1.txt` and `out2.txt` should be the same.
I attached this Pin tool to some programs such as `/bin/ls`. For them, `out1.txt` and `out2.txt` are the same. But when I attach it to `gcc` compiling a code, `out1.txt` would have more lines than `out2.txt`. `out2.txt` has a number of lines that is equal to `instrCount`, which seems reasonable. It seems that there's a problem with the `fstream` corresponding to `out1.txt`. `out1.txt` has a number of duplicate lines as compared to `out2.txt`.

These snippets show where they start to differ (marked with `<`):

out1.txt:

```
7f87ceb050a2
7f87ceb050a4
7f87ceb050a5
7f87ceb050a8
7f87ceb050aa
7f87ceb050b2
7f87ceb050b7
7f87ceb050b9
<7f87ceb050a4
<7f87ceb050a5
<7f87ceb050a8
<7f87ceb050aa
<7f87ceb050b2
<7f87ceb050b7
<7f87ceb050b9
<7f87ceb050b2
45218c
<7f87ceb050b7
45218e
<7f87ceb050b9
452190
```

out2.txt:

```
7f87ceb050a2
7f87ceb050a4
7f87ceb050a5
7f87ceb050a8
7f87ceb050aa
7f87ceb050b2
7f87ceb050b7
7f87ceb050b9
45218c
45218e
452190
```

I used a `PIN_LOCK` inside `instruction` function, but that doesn't change anything. I also tried to write into output files using `fprintf`, but the problem still exists.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: What exactly is "pin"?

Comment: Intel's dynamic binary instrumentation tool https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool

Comment: You don't need to tell an `ofstream` to open with `out` mode, that's implied by using an `ofstream` (rather than `ifstream` or `fstream`).